# Invoking functions returned by methods that take implicits

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, implicit

Given the following function:

```scala
def foo()(implicit count: Int): (String => Seq[String]) = {
  s => for (i <- 1 until count) yield s
}
```

Calling `apply()` on the result explicitly works:

```scala
implicit val count = 5

val x = foo().apply("x") // <- works fine
```

And setting the result to a `val`, which you then call as a function, works:

```scala
val f: String => Seq[String] = foo()
f("y") // <- works fine
```

But trying to do it all in one line, without `apply`, confuses the compiler into thinking you're passing the implicit explicitly:

```scala
val z = foo()("z") // type mismatch; found: String("z"), required: Int
```

Is there a way to do this without either the explicit `apply` or the intermediate `val`? For instance, is it possible somehow to move the `implicit` declaration into the returned anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> (foo() _)("z")
res10: Seq[String] = Vector(z, z, z, z)
```